# Yii2 HTML5 Server-Sent Events not real time on server

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii2, server-sent-events

I have a long running task (for loop with 1 second sleep in each iteration) and I want to update a progress bar in each iteration.

I used HTML5 Server-Sent Events but request status is pending for 10 sec and after it update progress bar done, which means it's not realtime.

I checked my code on many PC, Laptop, Phone, ... with various of OS and web browsers. It's working on all of them, just on my laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium it's not working. While it's working on localhost and also I found a demo of SSE on internet ([SSE Demo](http://demo.howopensource.com/sse/)), it's working on my laptop too.

[image: Start Task]

[image: End of task]

view file (sse.php):

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Server-Sent Event');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$js = '

var es;
  
function startTask() {
    es = new EventSource("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('province/default/sse').'");
      
    //a message is received
    es.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        var result = JSON.parse( e.data );
          
        addLog(result.message);       
          
        if(e.lastEventId == "CLOSE") {
            addLog("Received CLOSE closing");
            es.close();
            var pBar = document.getElementById("progressor");
            pBar.value = pBar.max; //max out the progress bar
        }
        else {
            var pBar = document.getElementById("progressor");
            pBar.value = result.progress;
            var perc = document.getElementById("percentage");
            perc.innerHTML   = result.progress  + "%";
            perc.style.width = (Math.floor(pBar.clientWidth * (result.progress/100)) + 15) + "px";
        }
    });
      
    es.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        addLog("Error occurred");
        es.close();
    });
}
  
function stopTask() {
    es.close();
    addLog("Interrupted");
}
  
function addLog(message) {
    var r = document.getElementById("results");
    r.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
    r.scrollTop = r.scrollHeight;
}

$(document).on("click", "#start_task", function() {
    startTask();
});

$(document).on("click", "#stop_task", function() {
    stopTask();
});

';
$this->registerJs($js);
?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="box box-solid  box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
    
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="start_task" value="Start Long Task" />
        <input type="button" id="stop_task" value="Stop Task" />
        <br />
        <br />
          
        <p>Results</p>
        <br />
        <div id="results" style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px; width:300px; height:250px; overflow:auto; background:#eee;"></div>
        <br />
          
        <progress id='progressor' value="0" max='100' style=""></progress>  
        <span id="percentage" style="text-align:right; display:block; margin-top:5px;">0</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller file (DefaultController):

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\province\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;

/**
 * Default controller for the `province` module
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function actionTestSse()
    {
         return $this->render('sse');       
    }
    
    public function actionSse()
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        
        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $this->send_message($i, 'on iteration ' . $i . ' of 10' , $i*10); 
            sleep(1);
        }
        $this->send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete', 100);
    }
    
    public function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
        $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);
          
        echo "id: $id" . "\n\n";
        echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . "\n\n";
        echo "\n\n";
          
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your request is not finished until the end of your action, that is when the server actually sends back the response, which is the whole 10 cycles. The action you configure for Server-sent Events is the one to check the status, not the one doing the actual work.

Comment: marche it's working on localhost, but not on server and today I checked it on android with chrome, it's working!! not working yet on windows with chrome or Firefox!!

Comment: I can't see how it would work with the code you have. Every tirme you use send_message, whatever you echo does not get sent back to the user, that is why you get a status of pending for the whole 10 seconds of the request. Everything you echo is sent back to the user as the response of the single request the HTML5 Server-Sent Event does.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after doing some testing here is an example.

First the Controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Task;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionTask() {
        return $this->render('task');
    }

    public function actionDoTask() {
        $task = Task::find()->one();
        if($task === null) {
            $task = new Task();
        }
        $task->totalIterations = 10;
        $task->started = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $task->iteration = 0;
        $task->percentage = 0;
        $task->save();

        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            sleep(1);
            $task->iteration = $i;
            $task->percentage = ($i * 100) / $task->totalIterations;
            $task->save();
        }
        return 'Some Result';
    }

    public function actionCheckTaskProgress() {
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

        $task = Task::find()->one();
        if($task !== null) {
            $data = ['message' => "on iteration " . $task->iteration . " of " . $task->totalIterations, 'progress' => $task->percentage];
        }
        else {
            $data = ['message' => "on iteration 0 of ?", 'progress' => 0];
        }

        echo "data: " . json_encode($data) . "\n\n";

        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'HTML5 Server-Sent Events';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$js = '

var es;

var xmlHttp;

function startTask() {
    // Do an async request for some result
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            es.close();
            addLog(xmlHttp.responseText);
            var pBar = document.getElementById("progressor");
            pBar.value = 100;
            var perc = document.getElementById("percentage");
            perc.innerHTML   = "100%";
            perc.style.width = (Math.floor(pBar.clientWidth) + 15) + "px";
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/do-task').'", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    setTimeout(function(){
        es = new EventSource("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('site/check-task-progress').'");

        es.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
            var result = JSON.parse( e.data );
            if(result.progress == 100) {
                es.close();
            }
            addLog(result.message);

            var pBar = document.getElementById("progressor");
            pBar.value = result.progress;
            var perc = document.getElementById("percentage");
            perc.innerHTML   = result.progress  + "%";
            perc.style.width = (Math.floor(pBar.clientWidth * (result.progress/100)) + 15) + "px";
        });
    }, 100);
}

function addLog(message) {
    var r = document.getElementById("results");
    r.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
    r.scrollTop = r.scrollHeight;
}

$(document).on("click", "#start_task", function() {
    startTask();
});

';

$this->registerJs($js);
?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="box box-solid  box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">

        <br />
        <input type="button" id="start_task" value="Start Long Task" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <p>Results</p>
        <br />
        <div id="results" style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px; width:300px; height:250px; overflow:auto; background:#eee;"></div>
        <br />

        <progress id='progressor' value="0" max='100' style=""></progress>  
        <span id="percentage" style="text-align:right; display:block; margin-top:5px;">0</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

My results:

[image: HTML5 Server-Sent Events Demo Results]

Comment: thanks for your example, but i checked my code on many PC, Laptop, Phone, ... with various of OS and web browsers. it's working on all of them, just on my laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium not working!!!